# Cocos2d-x onEnter and other default method not called

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have 2years experience in cocos2d but today started cocos2d-x. I just written derrived menu button class that not fire any default method like onEnter, selected and all.

Here is my code:

//MyButton.h

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include "cocos2d.h"

using namespace cocos2d;
class MyButton : public CCMenuItemSprite
{
    public:

    void onEnter();

    void selected();

};
```

//MyButton.mm

```
void MyButton::onEnter()
{
    CCPoint pos = this->getSelectedImage()->getPosition();
    CCSize  size = this->getSelectedImage()->getContentSize();


    this->getSelectedImage()->setPosition(ccp(pos.x+size.width*0.5f,  pos.y+size.height*0.5f));
    this->getSelectedImage()->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0.5f,0.5f));
}

void MyButton::selected()
{
    if (isEnabled())
    {
        if (this->getSelectedImage())
        {
            CCScaleTo *scale = CCScaleTo::create(0.5f, 1.3f);

            this->getSelectedImage()->runAction(scale);
        }
    }

}

MyButton * MyButton::create(CCNode* normalSprite, CCNode* selectedSprite, CCObject* target, SEL_MenuHandler selector)
{
    MyButton *btn = (MyButton*)CCMenuItemSprite::create(normalSprite, selectedSprite,target, selector);

    return btn;
}
```

//Here is code that creates button

```
CCSprite *start_1   = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(FRAME_MM_START);
CCSprite *start_2   = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(FRAME_MM_START);

MyButton *btnPlay =(MyButton*) MyButton::create(start_1,
                                                 start_2,
                                                 this,
                                                 menu_selector(MyMainMenu::playGame));

btnPlay->setPosition(ccp(mS.width*0.5f, mS.height*0.5f));
btnPlay->mMaxScale = 1.2f;

CCMenu* menu = CCMenu::create();
menu->setAnchorPoint( ccp(0,0) );
menu->setPosition( ccp(0,0) );
this->addChild(menu, 1);

menu->addChild(btnPlay);
```

Comment: is the method signature correct, and have you tested that the super method gets called?

Comment: how to test, I used like it is in Cocos2d-iphone, which is alternative for onEnter?

Comment: test by setting a breakpoint in the super class' onEnter method

Comment: yes selected() is called in CCMenuItemSprite but not in MyButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding something important:

In your MyButton class, you don't have a create method. what you did is just create a CCMenuItemSprite instance and cast it to a button. THIS IS WRONG.

you should add something in `MyButton`

public static MyButton* create(CCSprite* normal_sprite, CCSprite* selected_sprite, ...);

please find the `CCMenuItemSprite` class as an example.

first question, is `CCMenuItemSprite::onEnter()` virtual?

second, I guess your onEnter should be looks like below

```
void MyButton::onEnter()
{
    CCMenuItemSprite::onEnter();
    CCPoint pos = this->getSelectedImage()->getPosition();
    CCSize  size = this->getSelectedImage()->getContentSize();


    this->getSelectedImage()->setPosition(ccp(pos.x+size.width*0.5f, pos.y+size.height*0.5f));
    this->getSelectedImage()->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0.5f,0.5f));
}
```

this is how c++ works. it is different with objective-c, which allow method overloading by default.

```
MyButton * MyButton::create(CCNode* normalSprite, CCNode* selectedSprite, CCObject* target, SEL_MenuHandler selector)
{    
    MyButton *pRet = new MyButton();
    pRet->initWithNormalSprite(normalSprite, selectedSprite, null, target, selector); 
    pRet->autorelease();
    return pRet;
}
```

Comment: now added MyButton::create but still not working..updated my question..please look at it and tell me my mistake.

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor I've updated my answer. can you have a try? and if CCMenuItemSprite::onEnter() is not virtual, make it virtual.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Then in cocos2d-x we need to add all function in derived class when we customize class..oh..lots extra :-

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor exactly. take it easy.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `onEnter()` and `selected()` as `virtual`. `onEnter()` and `selected()` are derived methods from `CCMenuItemSprite` so they need to be declared as `virtual` to override them. If not overridden, your app calls `CCMenuItemSprite::onEnter()` and not `MyButton::onEnter()`.

Try reading more about it [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/122-virtual-functions/)

```
#include "cocos2d.h"

using namespace cocos2d;
class MyButton : public CCMenuItemSprite {
public:
    virtual void onEnter();
    virtual void selected();
};
```

Comment: ya got it...long back studied C++ and after learning obj.C forgot all :)